# How to log out of Facebook without any dialog box popping up?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Every time I try to programatically logout of Facebook from my application I get a dialog box saying Logged in using Facebook and gives me only two option and those are logout and cancel. I want to get rid of this dialog box and do the logout in background. I can not figure out how to do this. Some one please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this, the reason why is because it is poor security practice to allow said actions without user interaction.!